# Node.js passport skips strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This coffee-script passport implementation looks just like the examples to me but fails every time and never prints "Trying out the strategy".  I just get redirected to "/fail".  I tried naming the strategy as well as executing it in the (req, res, next) handler. I also verified that the form posted sent the username and password in those fields and tried renaming them with a mapping in the strategy according to the examples to no avail.  Any tips on what I'm overlooking?

```
pass = require 'passport'
strat = require('passport-local').Strategy
exp = require 'express'
app = exp.createServer()

# Configure strategy
pass.use new strat (username, password, done) ->
    #Logic to find user
    console.log("Trying out the strategy")
    user = {nm:username,ps:password}
    done(null,user)

app.configure () ->
    app.use (req,res,next) ->
        console.log("GOT A REQ")
        next()
    app.use pass.initialize()

ops = { failureRedirect: '/fail' }
app.post '/auth', pass.authenticate('local',ops), (req, res, next) ->
    console.log "what about here"

app.listen 1337
```

**Solution**  Modify express configuration:

```
app.configure () ->
    app.use exp.bodyParser()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this problem was due to my ignorance of express.  I was sending the username and password but wasn't parsing it - app.configure requires express.bodyParser() in order to utilize the strategies.

Comment: Ah, right!  Yes, the express boiler-plate is a little annoying, but occasionally there's something you don't need and then it's nice the different components are optional.

Comment: LOVE, LOVE, LOVE! I was modifying my passport related code beyond all recognition trying to solve this, before stumbling into your SO post. It turned out everything was actually working from the beginning. Only bodyParser was missing.

Answer (score 1):

If your getting redirected to /fail, it suggests to me that Passport is handling the request and authentication isn't successful.  Maybe a dumb suggestion, but are you POSTing a form with `username` and `password` fields?  If either of those are not present, that is the primary failure case in the local strategy.

Comment: I've watched network traffic and I see username and password set with their respective values coming across in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

I find the coffee script stuff unbelievably messy to read (maybe post the compiled JS version, too, unless someone who reads the coffee grounds better than I comes by).   Anyway, assuming your syntax around calling pass.authenticate is correct (I usually call it with a custom callback where I handle the response) the two things that stands out are:

1) you don't have a passport.serializeUser and deserializeUser setup.

2) unless you call authenticate with session:false and do your own session setup, I think having connect/express sessions loaded and configured is required.

Comment: I set { session:false } and it still didn't use my strategy.  I'll try setting up sessions next.  Also changing to js above.